# Auto benchmarking com lua

Tags: c, c++, lua

Um script em C ou C++ poderia escrever algoritmos em Lua (por *brute force*, isto é, testar várias combinações possíveis) baseado em um banco de dados com os resultados dos algoritmos.

A ideia é chegar ao algoritmo mais eficiente para determinado objetivo, por exemplo, desenvolvi um algoritmo para cálculo de estatísticas, quero chegar a um mais eficiente, sem perder o foco.

Existe alguma biblioteca ou maneira de testar a velocidade de um código em Lua ou C/C++ usando C++?

Comment: Não sei se essa estratégia de força bruta é uma boa idéia. Em primeiro lugar, no caso geral é impossível escrever um algoritmo para decidir se um dado programa obedece a uma dada especificação  - os seus testes com o banco de dado permitirão falsos positivos. Além disso, o seu espaço de busca de cresce exponencialmente com o comprimento do programa o que quer dizer que você vai precisar de muita sorte pra conseguir encontrar alguma solução não trivial.

Answer (score 4):

Não está tão claro como você está a gerar os algoritmos em lua, mas há duas formas simples de fazer executar o código. A primeira é lincar seu programa com o interpretador de lua como uma biblioteca. Então você pode executar código que esteja em uma string carregando ele com [`luaL_loadstring`](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/pt/manual.html#luaL_loadstring) e então invocando [`lua_pcall`](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/pt/manual.html#lua_pcall). A outra maneira seria salvar o script em um arquivo e então usar [`system("lua myscript.lua")`](http://pt.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/system), dado que o interpretador esteja instalado no seu sistema.

Tendo isso você pode fazer um benchmark bem simples, mas não tão preciso, usando a função [`clock()`](http://pt.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/c/clock) do C. Ou as classes [`chrono`](http://pt.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono) do C++. A ideia está em medir o tempo antes e depois da execução e calcular a diferença. Vale notar que é importante fazer múltiplas medições para garantir um bom resultado.